# icons not bouncing at all when I open them

Tags: applications, macos, dock, icon

I was forced to do a fresh install of El Cap. Now when I click on an app to open it, it will not bounce, not even once to acknowledge that the app is opening.

How do I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select `Animate opening Applications` option from Dock `Preferences`:

[image]